# Violin plot of ggplot2 is not in order as in dataset on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, violin-plot

I created the [image: violin plot] using below code, But **on the x-axis, Models name are not in order as in the data set** (i.e. "Observed", "SVM", "Grid_SVM", "MARS", "Grid_Mars", "RF", "Grid_RF").
Where the edit is required in the code?

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Model, y = Pb), cex.lab = 18, cex.axis=18) +
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE, fill = "palegreen") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .12, fill = "orange", outlier.color = "orange", outlier.size = 2) + 
  labs(title = "Pb Adsorption distribution by Models over testing phase") + xlab("Models") + ylab("Pb Adsorption distribution")+ theme_classic() +
  theme(
  plot.title = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"), #for Main Title
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"), #for axix title
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="darkblue", size=12, angle=0), #for axis tick
  axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=12, angle=0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ggplot2 plots character vectors in alphabetical order.  To place a specified order to your plot, simply use dplyr and create the column as a `factor()` and specify the levels you desire.  Then ggplot2 should plot it as you want.

**Edit #1**
One way is to modify the `df1` data frame separately from your string of ggplot2 commands.  You can do this as

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate( Model=factor(Model,levels=c("Observed", "SVM", "Grid_SVM", "MARS", "Grid_Mars", "RF", "Grid_RF")) )
```

And then call your string of ggplot2 commands as you have posted above.

**Edit #2** (from comments below)

If you want to pipe everything through and do everything in one shot, try

```
df1 %>%
  mutate( Model=factor(Model,levels=c("Observed", "SVM", "Grid_SVM", "MARS", "Grid_Mars", "RF", "Grid_RF")) ) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = Model, y = Pb), cex.lab = 18, cex.axis=18) +
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE, fill = "palegreen") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .12, fill = "orange", outlier.color = "orange", outlier.size = 2) + 
  labs(title = "Pb Adsorption distribution by Models over testing phase") + xlab("Models") + ylab("Pb Adsorption distribution")+ theme_classic() +
  theme(
  plot.title = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"), #for Main Title
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"), #for axix title
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="darkblue", size=12, angle=0), #for axis tick
  axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=12, angle=0))
```

The original suggestion was to overwrite the data.  Then generate the plot in a new chain.

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate( Model=factor(Model,levels=c("Observed", "SVM", "Grid_SVM", "MARS", "Grid_Mars", "RF", "Grid_RF")) )

ggplot( df1, aes(x = Model, y = Pb), cex.lab = 18, cex.axis=18) +
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE, fill = "palegreen") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .12, fill = "orange", outlier.color = "orange", outlier.size = 2) + 
  labs(title = "Pb Adsorption distribution by Models over testing phase") + xlab("Models") + ylab("Pb Adsorption distribution")+ theme_classic() +
  theme(
  plot.title = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"), #for Main Title
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"), #for axix title
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="darkblue", size=12, angle=0), #for axis tick
  axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=12, angle=0))
```

Either of the above will work.

Comment: There is also an `order` aesthetic with ggplot2.  I have never used it, but you may want to try that as well.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, for the first answer, how to perform, kindly describe or give a clue

Comment: I got the when used the latest suggestion: Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: First three line: df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Model=factor(Model,levels=c("Observed", "SVM", "Grid_SVM", "MARS", "Grid_Mars", "RF", "Grid_RF"))) %>%
  ggplot(df1, aes(x = Model, y = Pb))

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I used the original suggestion and then call ggplot, this work perfectly. However, I will keep the second suggestion as well thank you so much.